# How to Add a Computer or User to an OU in Group Policy Management Console (GPMC.msc)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, organizational-unit

On my Windows 2008R2 domain controller, I am trying to add computer objects into an organization unit (OU) in GPMC - so that I could apply a group policy objects (GPO) to that OU.

In GMPC I have created an OU called NY_Computers. I wish to add to this OU the computer PC_WIN7 defined in AD (Active Directory) - but I am unable to do this.

Right-mouse clicking on the  NY_Computers OU will only allow me to create another sub-OU (no where can I create a new computer or user or group)

NB: I can do this in AD Users & Computers console - but then I am unable to create any GPO (withing AD Users & Computers)

Am I overlooking something obvious ?

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not overlooking something. They're two different tools for doing two different things. Use ADUC for creating, modifying, etc. Users, Groups, OU's, etc. and use GPMC for creating, modifying, etc. Group Policy objects.

(You can use the GPMC to create, modify, etc. OU's, but just use ADUC for that).

Comment: Using GPMC, how do I apply a GPO to an OU created in ADUC (since OU created with ADUC - is not visible in GPMC) ?

Comment: You should be able to see your OU's in GPMC. If you're not seeing them then either refresh your view or close and re-open the GPMC.

Comment: That was it - I needed to refresh my view. Thanks @joeqwerty for pointing it out